# Java substring increments

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java substring manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692662/java-substring-manipulation)

I'm new to java and am trying to print an incremental substring. What I mean by this is that the user inputs a string, and the string is printed in increments. For example, the user inputs "I like me." and its saved as a String. The program would then out-print:

```
I
I
I l
I li
I lik
I like
I like
I like m
I like me
I like me.
```

The code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Substring{
    public static void main(String[] args){

  String substring;
  do{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a string consisting of at least one character: ");
    substring = in.nextLine();
  } while(substring.indexOf(" ") == -1);

  String letter = substring.indexOf(0);
  do{
    System.out.println(letter);
    letter = substring.indexOf();
  } while(!letter.equals(substring));
```

The first do-while statement checks that something is entered into the string. The second do-while statement is supposed to out print the new string each time until letter equals substring. I understand this is a confusing question and badly worded, but being new to Java I'm unsure on how to word it professionally.

Comment: Didn't they just closed this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692662/java-substring-manipulation

Comment: read String.substring documentation

Comment: @gtgaxiola user1701604 is skillful on paraphrasing his own contents =)

Comment: I asked the same question twice because I really need help and I added everything the people asked for that the last question. I have no clue where to go from here and just need help.

Comment: The hint from the comment is enough to proceed. If you really have no idea, then you have to review on your programming basics.

Comment: First thing to do would be to make sure your code compile, cause it doesn't. indexOf on a String doesn't return a String.

Answer (score 5):

You need something like:

```
for (int i=1; i<substring.length(); i++)
    System.out.print(substring.substring(0,i));
```

Comment: Is that java?  `substring(0,1)` ?

Comment: System.out.println(substring11.substring(0,i);   assuming substring11 is the string read from the console. (instead of substring , which is confusing)

Comment: you are welcome @ dan , +1 for quick edit

Answer (score 0):

> The first do-while statement checks that something is entered into the string.

No, the first do-while checks that the string doesn't have a space character (" ").

If you want to make sure there is something in the string you should do:

```
while (substring.length() == 0);
```

Then i would do a for-loop similar to @Dan posted.